# EF Core 7 DbCommandInterceptor does not intercept when used with EFCore.BulkExtensions.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, efcore.bulkextensions

I'm using EF Core 7 on MySql with `EFCore.BulkExtensions` and I'm calling `BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync` to Upsert some clients in my database.

```
public class Client : ITimeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to update `CreationDate` and/or `ModificationDate` based on the operation. If insert set both, if update set only `ModificationDate`. I have used the below interceptor to achieve this:

```
public class MyInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> NonQueryExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, 
                                                                              CommandEventData eventData, 
                                                                              InterceptionResult<int> result, 
                                                                              CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var entries = eventData.Context.ChangeTracker.Entries<ITimeEntity>();
        foreach (EntityEntry<IAuditedEntity> entry in entries)
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    entry.Entity.ModificationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.ModificationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return base.NonQueryExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

But I can see that the entries is empty. How can I achieve this

Comment: You cannot use interceptor with third party extensions if they do not support them. `BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync` do not use `ChangeTracker` to insert or update items, it generates temporary table, BulkCopy data into it and applies SQL Merge operator.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the above then?

Comment: Just checked their source code - No. But you can achieve this with other extension which I maintain [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore).

Comment: @pantonis maybe you can manually set the props on the source and then exclude the creation date on update: `ctx.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(..., config => config.PropertiesToExcludeOnUpdate.Add("CreationDate"))`. It is not a direct equivalent but potentially can get the job done.

Comment: @Guru You are a guru. Thank you that did the trick. Post it as an answer maybe this will help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `EFCore.BulkExtensions` package seems to not use `ChangeTracker` in this case you can workaround by manually assigning the `CreationDate` and `ModificationDate` to all the bulk processed data and then exclude the creation date for on update. Something along these lines:

```cs
// set the CreationDate and ModificationDate
// ...
ctx.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(..., config => config.PropertiesToExcludeOnUpdate.Add("CreationDate"))
```