# Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore bulk methods are not utilizing my 'context save changes intercept', how to intercept changes in them

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

My context has an overide of the save changes method that does the following:

```
 public static void SetAuditProperties(this ChangeTracker changeTracker)
        {
            changeTracker.DetectChanges();

            IEnumerable<EntityEntry> entities =
                changeTracker
                    .Entries()
                    .Where(t => t.Entity is AuditableEntity && (t.State == EntityState.Modified || t.State == EntityState.Deleted || t.State==EntityState.Added));
            if (entities.Any())
            {
                DateTime timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;

                foreach (EntityEntry entry in entities)
                {
                    AuditableEntity entity = (AuditableEntity)entry.Entity;

                    switch (entry.State)
                    {
                        case EntityState.Added:
                            if (entry.Entity is CepaReception)
                            {
                                CepaReception recep = (CepaReception)entry.Entity;
                            }
                            entity.CreatedOn = timestamp;
                            entity.UpdatedOn = timestamp;
                            entity.isOnProduction = false;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Modified:
                            if (entry.Entity is CepaReception)
                            {
                                CepaReception recep = (CepaReception)entry.Entity;
                            }
                            entity.UpdatedOn = timestamp;
                            entity.isOnProduction = false;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Deleted:
                            entity.UpdatedOn = timestamp;
                            entity.IsDeleted = true;
                            entity.isOnProduction = false;
                            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It basically updates different columns depending whether an entity was added, modified, or delete.

When i insert a bunch of new Entities using

```
context.<some db set>.BulkInsert(<listOfModels>);
```

It does not run my interceptor above. How do i make Bulk insert work with this interceptor? Thank you!

I cant find any recource online to help me do this

Comment: You can't. Extension just do not work with ChangeTracker.

Comment: that is sad to hear, thanks

Comment: Not for `Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore` but another library - `EFCore.BulkExtensions` [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75411297/2501279), maybe something similar can be achieved with `Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore`.

Comment: Ended up doing something similar. Made 'added' case of the change tracker interceptor into a function and I call it manually before bulk insert.